# when adding "Google services" library to the android project it hangs/takes forever when starting

Tags: android, google-play-services

i have a android project, which I can start from my eclipse.
when adding the google play services as an external library as described in the tutorial "https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html" ( see screenshot 1), I cant start the project anymore 
The startsequence hangs/takes forever as shown in screenshot 2 and ends with screen 3

Any hints ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

When removing the referenced library it start quick again.

Comment: have you recently updated your adt??

Comment: What is adt ? I just have updated 7 packages with Android SDK Manager and I have added GooglePlayServices rev.17. and Google Analytics App Tracking SDK Rev.3. At the end I would like to use the GoogleAnalytics features.

Comment: android developer tools. I had some problems like this after update. But mine is just slow takes more time than normal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In eclipse.ini (/etc/eclipse.ini) change `-Xms40m -Xmx384m` to `-Xms512m -Xmx512m`and restart eclipse. It should fix your issue.

Comment: thanks. I also removed some older versions of Android API's (<11)

Comment: if this pc roasting going to happen at every launch ? if then i am better off using dropbox api